# Searching a TreeMap with concatenated values

Tags: java, treemap

Suppose I add an item to a defined TreeMap like:

```
directory.put(personsLastName + personsFirstName, " Email - " + personsEmail 
                        + ", Class Status - " + studentStatus);
```

if I try to do something like:

```
boolean blnStudentExists = directory.containsValue("freshman");
```

it will always come out false. I am wondering if this has to do with the way I am populating the map? If so, how can I find all values in the map that are students? My goal is to print just students. Thanks.

Comment: How can `freshman`  ever be equal to `Email - <something>, Class Status - <something>`?

Comment: the variable studentStatus gets set to either freshman, sophomore, junior or senior.

Comment: What are you putting in the map? What are the values of the argument (first being the key, second being the value) to `put`?

Comment: the entry in the map would be something like: `LastFirst: abc@def.com, Class Status - Freshman`

Comment: That's not what your code does at all. Look  at the javadoc of `put`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does, because I have tested it. Entries into the map are successful. I am just trying to search those entries.

Comment: Look at the string concatenation in the code you posted. Where do you see `LastFirst`? Even if that was what you were putting in there, that entire `String` is the value. There is no way it will ever match just `freshman`, which, on top of it all, is lowercase.

Comment: personLastName, personFirstName, personEmail and studentStatus are all variables. My last comment was an example of what an entry might look like. Any way moving on.

Comment: It doesn't matter what they are. The value you are storing in the map will look like `Email - <something>, Class Status - <something>`. The method `containsValue` will check for the value you specify. In thise case, you've specified `freshman`.  Do you think it is possible for the String `Email - <something>, Class Status - <something>` to be equal to `freshman`?

Comment: I don't know where that came from. Do you see where I'm going with my questions?

Comment: @kl654 Sotirios is trying to help you understand why this approach would never work, so instead of asking for help trying to make your approach work, you'll consider another approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please re-read the TreeMap Javadocs - or the generic [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Map.html) interface, for that matter - and be very familiar with them for what you're trying to do here.

`.containsValue()` will search for specific, *exact* matches in the domain of values that you have inserted into your Map - nothing more, nothing less.  You can't use this to search for partial strings.  So if you inserted a value of `abc@def.com, Class Status - Freshman`, `.containsValue` will only return `true` for `abc@def.com, Class Status - Freshman` - not just for `Freshman`.

Where does this leave you?

1. You could write your own "search" routine that iterates through each value in the map, and performs substring matching for what you are searching for.  Not efficient for large numbers of values.  You will also need to worry about the potential for confusing delimiters between fields, if/as you add more.
2. You could create and use several parallel maps - one that maps to class statuses, another to emails, etc.
3. You could use a database (or an embedded database - pick your flavor) - which looks to be what you're trying to create here anyway.  Do you really need to re-create the wheel?

For this matter - you don't want to be searching by your values, anyway.  This goes against the exact purpose of a Map - Hash, Tree, or otherwise.  Searches by your keys are where any efficiencies will lie.  In most implementations (including the out-of-box TreeMap and HashMap) - searches against values will have to scan the entire Map structure anyway (or at least, until it can bail out after finding the first match).

Comment: I suspected it was because of the way I am concatenating the smaller values together to make one single value. Your explanation was helpful. Thank you.